# How to encrypt on external server for decryption within Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I have a requirement to pass sensitive data from the source server (running Craft CMS) to a Laravel API. As a result, I would like to encrypt the string at the source server so that the string can be decrypted in the Laravel API for processing.

Laravel has great [encryption out of the box](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/encryption) so I would prefer to use that for simplicity. How can I ensure the string is encrypted in the same format on the source server?

If this isn't possible (due to the environment difference), what is the next best alternative?

Comment: For those who have downvoted, I'm unsure how best to format this question with code example as I don't know the approach to use. If you are downvoting, please can you comment advising what I should do to better format this question?

Comment: You're worried about *encryption during transport*. You should solve this using the TLS (HTTPS) protocol, which was designed for this. Do proper certificate validation when sending to your HTTPS server to ensure its identity, the rest is handled by the TLS encryption.

Comment: @deceze I have HTTPS configured, it's just a requirement to have this string encrypted. Thanks for the clarification though :)

Answer (score 1):

When you encrypt something in Laravel, it returns a base64 encoded JSON string with all the necessary information: IV, encrypted string, HMAC.

To create a string in the format of the Laravel Encrypter, you can do the following.

1. Encrypt the string using 'AES-CBC'. While it is not the most recommended mode, it is the mode Laravel uses. You can use either 256 bit or 128 bit although you obviously should use 256 (Laravel also tries to serialize the passed value so you should do this too).
2. Create the HMAC with the function `hash_hmac()`. The parameters you need are the IV (base64 encoded) and the encrypted string. Concatenate them and use your encryption key to create the HMAC using `sha256` as the hashing algorithm.
3. Create an array with the IV, the encrypted string and the HMAC. Laravel uses the `compact()` function for this so I would do the same.
4. JSON encode the resulting array and base64 encode the resulting JSON string.

The result should be an encoded string that Laravel can decrypt with the correct key.

For reference: [The source code for the Encrypter class](https://github.com/illuminate/encryption/blob/master/Encrypter.php)

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for the direction. I'll look to implement your suggestion and will reply with the code so the question has a tangible code extract :)